# Alternatives to temporary table or view for optimizing reptitive query on small table

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with about 40,000 rows. Each has a space-separated list of numbers which range from 1 through 100. An example row has a unique identifying name in a column followed by, for example, "4 8 18 32" in another column.

I want to combine a free text search of the name with counts for the number of rows containing a certain number. So, for example, give me counts of how many rows match %word% and also each number 1 through 100. That's one hundred queries. If the above "4 8 18 32" was the only match in the table, then the counts would be 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, ... 8: 1, ... 32: 1.

Currently, I'm trying to use an InnoDB FULLTEXT index with a minimum token length of 1 to do this, and then doing the search in binary mode. My queries look like this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`numbers`) AGAINST ('+34' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `name` LIKE '%word%') as `34`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`numbers`) AGAINST ('+35' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `name` LIKE '%word%') as `35`,
```

And are joined into one result as such. This takes about two or three seconds, which is a very long time.

I tried using a temporary table for the LIKE match and then do just the boolean mode searches for numbers against that, but I cannot reuse a temporary table reference more than once in a query, and it's reused a hundred times here. I also tried creating a view of the LIKE portion, but did not see much speedup. Telling the view to use algorithm=temptable was not possible, since the fulltext index cannot transfer over.

Am I using the database in a fundamentally incorrect way? Is there a strategy that can make this significantly faster?

Comment: The first question I must ask, why do you have a column consisting of a  list of comma separated numbers as text rather than a separate table with a column of 8bit integers and a reference ID?  The parsing of all of those strings is a large performance issue, and the query can't be made materially more efficient in the current layout.

Comment: I will try out making another table with a separate row for each number. I thought turning a 40,000 row table into a 400,000 row table had the potential to make it even slower, given this is indexed with fulltext and all the searches are binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 100 separate queries, I would try only one query against the table:

```
SELECT 
       -- using CASE expression --
       SUM( case when `numbers` like '%+34%' and `name` LIKE '%word%'
                 then 1 else 0 end ) As `34`,
       -- or using IF ---
       SUM( IF( `numbers` like '%+35%' and `name` LIKE '%word%', 1, 0 )) As `35`
       .......
FROM table;
```

This query performs a full table scan over the table, but **only one scan**, not a series of 100 scans.
Could be that it will be faster - give it a try.
Full table scan is not an evil, index is not always good.

Comment: Depending on the width of the table it MIGHT be faster to move the `LIKE '%word%'` into the `WHERE`. This assumes there is an index on the `name` column and only a small fraction of the rows get returned. Otherwise I'll agree that a scan might not be so bad here after all...